# Rails Gretel not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, breadcrumbs

So I'm setting up a basic Gretel installation following instructions in https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel.

This is my breadcrumb.rb

```
crumb :root do
 link 'Root', root_path
end
```

And this is the code within the show.html.**haml** (My views are coded in haml)

```
= breadcrumb :root
```

And the application.html.haml

```
= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ", separator: " &rsaquo; "
```

Now the rendering I got is something like

http://grab.by/uyFW

Any idea what could be going wrong? I was expecting a breadcrumb with the test 'Root'

Comment: Could you please share the generated HTML source?

Comment: I can't the whole html, but here is the important part... is like is trying to render the object http://grab.by/uyGI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
= breadcrumb :root
= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ", separator: " &rsaquo; "
```

with

```
- breadcrumb :root

= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ", separator: " &rsaquo; "
```

Comment: Actually if I use `-` it stops working completely. No render at all

Comment: @Pablo i have updated the answer. You need `=` on the `breadcrumbs` and `-` on `breadcrumb`.

Comment: Is there a way to force rendering when a breadcrumb is root level and is the current page?

Comment: @Pablo didn't quite get your question? Do you mean to say that display  breadcrumb on root_path too.

Comment: Yes, currently it just skips rendering on that case. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Pablo have you read https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel page. In there you will see an option `:autoroot` you can pass this to your breadcrums by setting it to `True` I have never used HAML before but I think the following will work. `= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ", separator: " &rsaquo; ", autoroot: True`  Give it a try and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, the only problem in our case that we are trying to see breadcrumbs even for root page.

According to the gem wiki the parameter ":display_single_fragment" is set to false by default. The Parameter is quite self-explanatory.

The code below works as expected:

```
- breadcrumb :portfolios
= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ", separator: " &rsaquo; ", :autoroot => true, :display_single_fragment => true
```

Answer (score 2):

for link single link you have to "display_single_fragment" attribute to true in application controller

```
    <%= breadcrumbs pretext: "current link", display_single_fragment: "true" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
= breadcrumb :root
```

to

```
- breadcrumb :root
```

Hope it helps.